# Python convert email

Tags: python

I am writing a small program that reads in email and outputs only part of it.

Example

> someone.lastname@example.com

I want the output to be someonel

so in this case i want the first part of the email before the "." and then the first letter of the second part in this case "l"

I need some assistance on how to concatenate these 2 parts taking only one character from the second part after the "."

thank you in advance

Comment: Basic string operations..

Comment: `email = 'someone.lastname@example.com'; email[:email.find('.')+2]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
>>> first, rest = 'someone.lastname@example.com'.split('.', 1)
>>> first + rest[:1]
'someonel'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should find the index of the first occurrence of dot and then use this index to split the string.

```
st = 'someone.lastname@example.com'
dot_index = st.index('.')
new_st = st.rjust(st[dot_index + 2])
```

This returns an array for `new_st` that its first element is what you want.

I used +2, because the argument is the length, so we should +1 the index and the second +1 is for counting the next character after the dot.